Typescript. Try call api again if got any errors
I have function that calls API and returns result based on response.
But sometimes i could receive error or something else goes wrong. I want my code to try again until good response is received.
Example code:
for(let i = 0; i < someValues.length; i++) {
    await Test(someValues[i]);
}

async function Test(someValue: string): Promise<SomeObject | null> {
    try {
        const response: any = await someapi.call(someValue); // if got some error from api (connect etc.) then try again 
        if(response) {
            return response;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await Test(someValue);
        }, 100);
    }
}

Is this code will work? If first try will get api error, what would this loop above receive as response?
Also getting this error in Promise<SomeObject | null> :
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'


All function paths should return either SomeObject or null, you're only returning a value in the try scope, but not in the catch scope, you should probably return null after setTimeout.

Proper async retry in TypeScript ;)

The problem is that you're not returning anything in your catch block, so the function is implicitly returning undefined. If you want a delay before retry (a good call) you'll need to manage it differently.
Something like this would work:
for(let i = 0; i < someValues.length; i++) {
    await Test(someValues[i]);
}

async function Test(someValue: string): Promise<SomeObject | null> {
    try {
        const response: any = await someapi.call(someValue); // if got some error from api (connect etc.) then try again 
        if(response) {
            return response;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(async () => {
            resolve(await Test(someValue));
        }, 100));
    }
}

Alternatively, a slightly cleaner way you could do it is something like this in that block:
// Wait 100ms
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
// Retry
return await Test(someValue);

And a warning, if the call fails, you're going to infinitely recurse. You probably want to track some kind of count of attempts so you can abort at some point.

I think you should return the await Test(somevalue) in your setTimeout call.


    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(async () => {
            return await Test(someValue);
        }, 100);



